# How to modify wordpress theme without changing the code?

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I would like to modify my WordPress theme without changing the code. Specifically, I would like to show the number of minutes required to read the post, How can I do that?
Similare to showing posting date and author.

Comment: Use a plugin (or build your own) that hooks into the appropriate actions in the theme. If your theme doesn't provide the right hooks, you can create a child theme that inherits from your theme and only overrides the necessary files (while leaving the parent theme updateable).

Comment: Thanks that seems like a good answer, I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your Dashboard>Appearance>Themes>Customize

Make sure to install theme that has more than standard options.

Answer (score 0):

You can install a plugin as per: https://www.shoutmeloud.com/estimated-reading-time-wordpress-posts.html

There is a full installation and configuration tutorial here and you will get your desired result of showing how many minutes it will take to a read a post.